# Issue Building PHP / MySQL Join Query

Tags: php, mysql, join, relational-database

I am having some issues trying to construct this JOIN query. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

I have 3 tables here. 
Table A houses our "users." They are identified by the id number.
Table C houses locations identified by an id number.
Table B contains the connection between Table A and Table C. uid is the id of the user and lid is the id of the location. The user might be associated with multiple locations.

I need to build a query that will take the id of the user, find all of the locations that user's id is associated with and return them.

**Table A**

```
|     id     |     name     |
-----------------------------
|     0      |     steven   |
-----------------------------
|     1      |      etc     |
-----------------------------
```

**Table B**

```
|     id     |     uid      |     lid     |
-------------------------------------------
|     0      |      0       |      1      |
-------------------------------------------
|     1      |      1       |      1      |
-------------------------------------------
```

**Table C**

```
|     id     |   location_name   |
----------------------------------
|     0      |    santa monica   |
----------------------------------
|     1      |      hamptons     |
----------------------------------
```

Comment: `trying to construct this JOIN query` - and the result was...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try like below

```
SELECT 
    A.id as user_id,
    A.name as user_name,
    C.location_name as location
FROM
    TableA A
        JOIN
    TableB B ON A.id = B.uid
        JOIN
    TableC C ON B.lid = C.id
WHERE
    A.id = 0;
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks for the help I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, l.id, l.location_name
FROM users u
JOIN connection c
ON c.uid = u.id
JOIN locations l
ON c.lid = l.id
WHERE u.id=?
GROUP BY l.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   select A.name, C.location_name from B inner join A on B.uid=A.id inner join C on B.lid= C.id where A.id='".$id."' ;
```

here $id will be your userid entered by you

Answer (score 1):

I would say you remove that table B and have only table A and table C.

**Table A**

```
|     id     |     name     |
-----------------------------
|     0      |     steven   |
-----------------------------
|     1      |      etc     |
-----------------------------
```

**Table C**

```
|     id     |   location_name   |   uid  | 
-------------------------------------------
|     0      |    santa monica   |   0    |
-------------------------------------------   
|     1      |      hamptons     |   1    |
-------------------------------------------
```

The table C which I have proposed has a foreign key which references table A's `id`

Now you can have a query like,

```
select * from tableA A
inner join
tableB B on
A.id = B.uid
```

Comment: Thanks for the response I appreciate it. I actually need the linking table. More than 1 person can be linked with a location vice versa. Thank you though, I believe I can use the code to work with you provided for something else.Thanks!